# Как преобразовать std::chrono::time_point одного вида в другой?

Tags: c++, c++17, кроссплатформенность, std-chrono

Пишу кроссплатформенное приложение, в котором есть такой код:

```
auto last_write_file_time = std::filesystem::last_write_time(in_file_name);
time_t tt = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(last_write_file_time);
tm tast_write_file_time_in_tm = *std::localtime(&tt);
```

в этом участке я получаю время последнего изменения файла в структуре `tm`.

Проблема возникает при переносе этого участка на другую платформу. Функция `std::filesystem::last_write_time` возвращает `file_time_type` который является алиасом на `std::chrono::time_point` с каким то заранее заданным параметром. Вот только этот параметр меняется от компилятора к компилятору и соответственно если в gcc я могу передать объект `last_write_file_time` в функцию `std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t` без проблем, то MSVC это уже не компилирует из за несоответствия типа. Можно ли как то преобразовать `std::chrono::time_point` одного типа в другой? (Например из `std::chrono::time_point <system_clock>` сделать `std::chrono::time_point <steady_clock>`).

Comment: Не уверен, но думаю там то, что нужно: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/file_time_type

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, скорей всего не сработает — там точно такой же `std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t` как и у OP'а, только за ширмой `decltype`'а... вообще как-то странно, что стандарт позволяет возвращать время в часах отличных от `system_clock`... и что какие-то большие платформы этим пользуются... а вот конвертирование временных точек между `system_clock` и `steady_clock`, вообще говоря, не должно быть возможно т.к. последние отсчитываются от абсолютно произвольного момента времени...

Comment: с С++20 можно попробовать что-то вроде `using std::chrono; time_t tt = system_clock::to_time_t(clock_cast<system_clock>(last_write_file_time))`... нуда... на enSO всё тоже [выглядит печально](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51273205/how-to-compare-time-t-and-stdfilesystemfile-time-type).

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch ну я про то и говорю, что этот самый `/*trivial-clock*/` у gcc и MSVC разный. В Microsoft вообще туда какой-то свой тип зафигачили.

Comment: Грубую конвертацию сделать довольно просто(через `time_since_epoch`), но у этого способа есть недостатки. Поэтому предлагаю почитать [обсуждение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35282308/convert-between-c11-clocks) этого вопроса на EnSO, сделать выводы и выбрать подходящую для себя версию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробовал реализовать разные варианты решить задачу, в итоге привожу один из способов, может быть не самый короткий, но у меня под Windows/Linux на компиляторах MSVC/GCC/CLang, на всех работает верно.

Сама конверсия включает в себя две строки кода, которые начинаются с `static int64_t sfclock_diff...` и `std::time_t cftime = ...`, т.е. входом является `ftime` (результат вызова `std::filesystem::last_write_time(...)`), выходом `cftime` типа `time_t` (последний будет содержать Unix Time Stamp, т.е. количество секунд с `1970-01-01 00:00:00`).

После этого строки только для информативности, вывод времени на консоль конвертированное в локальное время системы.

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflowRu1003257#main.cpp)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    std::filesystem::path p = std::filesystem::current_path() / "0413.txt";
    { std::ofstream(p.c_str()).put('a'); } // create file
    auto ftime = std::filesystem::last_write_time(p);
    
    static int64_t sfclock_diff = []{
        auto diff = int64_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch() / std::chrono::milliseconds(1)) -
            int64_t(decltype(ftime)::clock::now().time_since_epoch() / std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
        return (diff + (diff < 0 ? -500 : 500)) / 1000; // Round to nearest second.
    }();
    
    std::time_t cftime = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(
        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>(
            std::chrono::seconds(ftime.time_since_epoch() / std::chrono::seconds(1) + sfclock_diff)
        )
    );
    
    std::cout << "File write time is " << std::asctime(std::localtime(&cftime)) << std::endl;
    std::filesystem::remove(p);
}
```

Вывод:

```
File write time is Wed Dec 23 09:12:29 2020
```